# How to call Explicit intent for result from fragments in tabbed activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I am using android Tabbed Activity with 3 tabs. Each tab contains a fragment. I am trying to call Camera Intent from the 3rd tab using startActivityForResult(x, y);
After I click the pic, the control returns to the activity, but not to the fragment which called the intent.
I tried switching to the desired tab from onActivityResult() method in the activity, only to realize that it is not being called either.
How Do I pass on the controls and intent to the desired fragment?

Comment: Have you tried to resume the desired fragment in `onResume`?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well, but it always goes back to the default fragment

Comment: Are you using `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: @MichaelLam Yes, I am.